# Deserializing xs:normalizedString in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml

According to https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#normalizedString

> 3.3.1 normalizedString
>
> [Definition:]   normalizedString represents white space normalized strings. The value space of normalizedString is the set of strings that do not contain the carriage return (#xD), line feed (#xA) nor tab (#x9) characters. The lexical space of normalizedString is the set of strings that do not contain the carriage return (#xD), line feed (#xA) nor tab (#x9) characters. The base type of normalizedString is string.

What's not mentioned in that paragraph is the implication of the whiteSpace facet restriction, that being set to `whiteSpace=replace` on xs:normalizedString, REF: https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#rf-whiteSpace

> 4.3.6 whiteSpace
>
> [Definition:]   whiteSpace constrains the value space of types derived from string such that the various behaviors specified in Attribute Value Normalization in [XML 1.0 (Second Edition)] are realized. The value of whiteSpace must be one of {preserve, replace, collapse}.
>
> **preserve**
>
> No normalization is done, the value is not changed (this is the behavior required by [XML 1.0 (Second Edition)] for element content)
>
> **replace**
>
> All occurrences of #x9 (tab), #xA (line feed) and #xD (carriage return) are replaced with #x20 (space)
>
> **collapse**
>
> After the processing implied by replace, contiguous sequences of #x20's are collapsed to a single #x20, and leading and trailing #x20's are removed.

Given that one would expect that when the .NET Framework deserializes the following class definition any instances of Tab, Linefeed or Carriage Return in the Value field will have been replaced with Space characters:

```cs
[XmlRoot("Root")]
public class Root
{
    [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
    public string Value;
}
```

Except that this isn't the case. It seems that .NET's idea of normalizedString is `whiteSpace=preserve` as `<Value> tabs\t\ttabs</Value>` gets deserialized as `tabs\t\ttabs` - a string with the tab characters still in it.

Can anybody show me how to setup the XmlSerializer class below such that all of the replacement tests actually pass?

```
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace Deserialize.Tests
{
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string CarriageReturns;

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string Newlines;

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string Spaces;

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string Tabs;
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class DeserializeTests
    {
        private const string xml = "<Root>" +
            "<CarriageReturns> returns\u000d\u000dreturns </CarriageReturns>" +
            "<Newlines> newlines\u000a\u000anewlines </Newlines>" +
            "<Spaces> spaces  spaces </Spaces>" +
            "<Tabs> tabs\t\ttabs </Tabs>" +
            "</Root>";

        private Root root;

        public void SetUp(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            //MemoryStream_SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            //StringReader_SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            //XmlDocument_SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            XmlTextReader_SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
        }

        public void MemoryStream_SetUp(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(memoryStream);
            }
        }

        public void StringReader_SetUp(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            using (var stringReader = new StringReader(xml))
            using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                xmlTextReader.Normalization = normalization;
                xmlTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = whitespaceHandling;

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
            }
        }

        public void XmlDocument_SetUp(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            var doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
            doc.LoadXml(xml);
            root = new Root()
            {
                //CarriageReturns = Normalize(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/CarriageReturns").InnerText),
                //Newlines = Normalize(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Newlines").InnerText),
                //Spaces = Normalize(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Spaces").InnerText),
                //Tabs = Normalize(doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Tabs").InnerText),

                CarriageReturns = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/CarriageReturns").InnerText,
                Newlines = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Newlines").InnerText,
                Spaces = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Spaces").InnerText,
                Tabs = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/Root/Tabs").InnerText,
            };
        }

        public void XmlTextReader_SetUp(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            using (var xmlTextReader = new XmlTextReader(memoryStream))
            {
                xmlTextReader.Normalization = normalization;
                xmlTextReader.WhitespaceHandling = whitespaceHandling;

                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(xmlTextReader);
            }
        }

        public string Normalize(string value)
        {
            if (System.String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) == false)
            {
                value = value.Replace('\u0009', ' ');
                value = value.Replace('\u000a', ' ');
                value = value.Replace('\u000d', ' ');
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object[] XmlTextReaderCases =
        {
            new object[] { false, WhitespaceHandling.All },
            new object[] { false, WhitespaceHandling.None },
            new object[] { false, WhitespaceHandling.Significant },
            new object[] { true, WhitespaceHandling.All },
            new object[] { true, WhitespaceHandling.None },
            new object[] { true, WhitespaceHandling.Significant },
        };

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource("XmlTextReaderCases")]
        public void CarriageReturns_should_be_replaced(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            Assert.That(root.CarriageReturns, Is.EqualTo(" returns  returns "));
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource("XmlTextReaderCases")]
        public void Newlines_should_be_replaced(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            Assert.That(root.Newlines, Is.EqualTo(" newlines  newlines "));
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource("XmlTextReaderCases")]
        public void Spaces_should_be_unchanged(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            Assert.That(root.Spaces, Is.EqualTo(" spaces  spaces "));
        }

        [Test]
        [TestCaseSource("XmlTextReaderCases")]
        public void Tabs_should_be_replaced(bool normalization, WhitespaceHandling whitespaceHandling)
        {
            SetUp(normalization, whitespaceHandling);
            Assert.That(root.Tabs, Is.EqualTo(" tabs  tabs "));
        }
    }
}
```

Note that XmlSerializer does actually replace the Carriage Return characters (\u000d) with Linefeeds (\u000a) so it is doing some basic normalization while deserializing the XML.

====

Edit to make the question perfectly clear:

Q: Can anybody show me how to setup the XmlSerializer class below such that all of the replacement tests actually pass?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell System.Xml.Serialization doesn't do anything meaningful when deserializing or serializing fields with `[XmlAttribute(DataType="normalizedString")]` applied, so there don't appear to be any settings you can apply to make it normalize whitespace correctly.

So far the only way I've been able to get acceptable results is to create a `NormalizedString` class implementing `IXmlSerializable` and use that in place of primitive `string` fields. A minimal implementation looks like the following:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XsdTypes
{
    public class NormalizedString : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public const char CR = '\u000d';
        public const char LF = '\u000a';
        public const char SPACE = '\u0020';
        public const char TAB = '\u0009';

        protected string value = null;

        public NormalizedString() { }

        public NormalizedString(NormalizedString value)
        {
            this.value = value.value;
        }

        public NormalizedString(String value)
        {
            this.value = NormalizeWhitespace(value);
        }

        public static string NormalizeWhitespace(string value)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                value = value.Replace(CR, SPACE).Replace(LF, SPACE).Replace(TAB, SPACE);
            }
            return value;
        }

        #region Class overrides

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return value;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IXmlSerializable

        XmlSchema IXmlSerializable.GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }

        void IXmlSerializable.ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            //TODO: This could be null
            value = NormalizeWhitespace(reader.ReadString());
            reader.Read();
        }

        void IXmlSerializable.WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            writer.WriteString(NormalizeWhitespace(value));
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

There's a lot more work implementing a generally useful class (`ICloneable`, `IComparable`, `IConvertible`, `IEquatable`, implicit operators, etc), but the above is sufficient to deserialize and serialize the following class correctly:

```
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString CarriageReturns;
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString Linefeeds;
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString Spaces;
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString Tabs;
    }
```

This seems a lot simpler than adding custom getters and setters every place I want an `xs:normalizedString` element.

> Be aware: If you try to decorate one of these NormalizedString fields with `[XmlElement(DataType="normalizedString")]` (or `DataType=anything`, really) you will get a run time exception:

```
System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportTypeMapping(TypeModel model, String ns, ImportContext context, String dataType, XmlAttributes a, Boolean repeats, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
InvalidOperationException : 'normalizedString' is an invalid value for the XmlElementAttribute.DataType property. The property may only be specified for primitive types.
```

The following set of NUnit3 tests exercise XML deserialization and serialization:

```
// Install-Package NUnit
// Install-Package NUnit3TestAdapter
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace XsdTypes.NormalizedStringTests.IXmlSerializable
{
    [XmlRoot("Root")]
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString CarriageReturns;
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString Linefeeds;
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString Spaces;
        [XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
        public NormalizedString Tabs;
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class NormalizedStringDeserializationTests
    {
        public Root root;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var xml =
                "<Root>\r\n" +
                " <CarriageReturns> returns\u000d\u000dreturns </CarriageReturns>\r\n" +
                " <Linefeeds> linefeeds\u000a\u000alinefeeds </Linefeeds>\r\n" +
                " <Spaces> spaces\u0020\u0020spaces </Spaces>\r\n" +
                " <Tabs> tabs\u0009\u0009tabs </Tabs>\r\n" +
                "</Root>\r\n";
            Deserialize(xml);
        }

        private void Deserialize(string xml)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml)))
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                root = (Root)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
            }
        }

        [Test]

        public void TestCarriageReturns()
        {
            string actual = root.CarriageReturns.ToString();
            Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(" returns  returns "));
        }

        [Test]

        public void TestLinefeeds()
        {
            string actual = root.Linefeeds.ToString();
            Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(" linefeeds  linefeeds "));
        }

        [Test]

        public void TestSpaces()
        {
            string actual = root.Spaces.ToString();
            Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(" spaces  spaces "));
        }

        [Test]

        public void TestTabs()
        {
            string actual = root.Tabs.ToString();
            Assert.That(actual, Is.EqualTo(" tabs  tabs "));
        }

    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class NormalizedStringSerializationTests
    {
        string xml;

        [SetUp]
        public void SetUp()
        {
            var root = new Root()
            {
                CarriageReturns = new NormalizedString(" returns\u000d\u000dreturns "),
                Linefeeds = new NormalizedString(" linefeeds\u000d\u000dlinefeeds "),
                Spaces = new NormalizedString(" spaces\u000d\u000dspaces "),
                Tabs = new NormalizedString(" tabs\u000d\u000dtabs ")
            };
            Serialize(root);
        }

        private void Serialize(Root root)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root));
                serializer.Serialize(stream, root);
                xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
            }
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestCarriageReturns()
        {
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<CarriageReturns> returns  returns </CarriageReturns>"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestLinefeeds()
        {
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<Linefeeds> linefeeds  linefeeds </Linefeeds>"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestNullables()
        {
            Serialize(new Root());
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<CarriageReturns xsi:nil=\"true\" />"));
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<Linefeeds xsi:nil=\"true\" />"));
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<Spaces xsi:nil=\"true\" />"));
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<Tabs xsi:nil=\"true\" />"));
        }

        [Test]
        public void TestSpaces()
        {
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<Spaces> spaces  spaces </Spaces>"));
        }

        [Test]

        public void TestTabs()
        {
            Assert.That(xml, Does.Contain("<Tabs> tabs  tabs </Tabs>"));
        }
    }
}
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following :

```
   public class Root
    {
        private string _CarriageReturns { get; set; }
        private string _Newlines { get; set; }
        private string _Spaces { get; set; }
        private string _Tabs { get; set; }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string CarriageReturns
        {
            get { return _CarriageReturns; }
            set { _CarriageReturns = value.Trim(); }
        }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string Newlines
        {
            get { return _Newlines; }
            set { _Newlines = value.Trim(); }
        }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string Spaces
        {
            get { return _Spaces; }
            set { _Spaces = value.Trim(); }
        }

        [XmlElement(DataType = "normalizedString")]
        public string Tabs
        {
            get { return _Tabs ; }
            set { _Tabs = value.Trim(); }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're not answering the question that was asked. Surrounding whitespace isn't the issue, the problem is that .NET's XmlSerializer class isn't replacing Tab (\u0009), Linefeed (\u000a) and Carriage Return characters (\u000d) with Space characters (\u0020) when deserializing xs:normalizedString values. I can certainly fix this with getters and setters, as you have illustrated with .Trim(), but then I have to do that everywhere I need to use xs:nomalizedString and, if I do that, why does .NET even have `[XmlElement(DataType="normalizedString')]` available as an option?

Comment: Put whatever code you want in the set statements to replace characters as required.  I did answer the question.